# Events in Windows

Tags: event-handling

How can i capture all user raised events in my application, is there any specific event which is parrent for all of user based(raised) events ?

eg :

mouse click,
  key press,
  etc.,
 these all events are raised by user can i able to capture it under one method???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Windows forms .NET, add the following to your main application form:

```
protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click += new EventHandler(Control_Click);
    e.Control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown);  
    base.OnControlAdded(e);
}

void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Hande all keydown events, sender is the control  
    Debug.WriteLine( sender.ToString() +  "  -  KeyDown");
}

void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Hande all click events, sender is the control  
    Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString() + "   -  Click");

}

protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyDown -= Control_KeyDown;
    e.Control.Click -= Control_Click;

    base.OnControlRemoved(e);
}
```

Just add any extra events you require (such as KeyPress, MouseEnter, MouseDown etc) in a similar manner.  This is a bit cleaner and simpler then delving into the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SetWindowsHookEx` API to set up a thread-local `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29) for full details.

That will call a single function in your application for every message you receive from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In one single method: yes.

You have to implement the [DefWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633572%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, which handles all events and messages. Unfortunately, not just user generated events but all. But you should be able to filter those out easily.